# Unit tests in meteor can't find the code they need to test

Tags: meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity, meteor-jasmine

I'm struggling with unit tests in Meteor. I want to use the velocity, jasmine package but I must be doing something wrong. The tests don"t seem to work because the test can't find the code to test. The test project is available on github.

The code that i want to test is here: 
https://github.com/robvanpamel/coderepository/blob/master/meteor/sandwich-app/server/Services/SandwichService.js

The unit Test is here: 
https://github.com/robvanpamel/coderepository/blob/master/meteor/sandwich-app/tests/jasmine/server/integration/spec/SandwichServiceSpec.js 
When I uncomment the created SandwichService in the Unit Test, the test works, which is normal.

I haven't done any configuration elsewhere in meteor, and i think that is the problem. Do you have to put a package.js file where you specify your source code? 
How can Jasmine know where it can find the SandwichService I'm trying to test? It is also the error i get. 
"ReferenceError: SandwichesService is not defined "

**EDIT**

I was able to resolve it and updated the code repository in GitHub. The key was not to use the Javascript prototypes. so the below will not work

```
function SandwichesService(){};

SandwichesService.prototype.listSandwiches = function() {
  // do stuff here
}
```

while the code below does work

```
SandwichService = {
  listSandwiches: function(){
      // do stuff here
  }
};
```

I don't really understand why? Does somebody can tell me?

Kind regards and thanks upfront! 
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Meteor issue not a testing issue :)

You need to put the SandwichesService on the global namespace. Your second block does that by default.

Try:

`SandwichService = new SandwichesService()`

(don't use var)